# Run script command/file in MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

I search through the half of the Internet but found either nothing or outdated solutions with `db.eval()`. Hence my question.

I have some code using mongo driver 3.5.0:

```
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase 'mydb'
println db.runCommand( new BasicDBObject( eval:'db.version()' ) )
```

> Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on mydb to execute command { eval: "db.version()", $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "mydb" }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on mydb to execute command { eval: \"db.version()\", $readPreference: { mode: \"secondaryPreferred\" }, $db: \"mydb\" }", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized" }
>       at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:115)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:107)

I can run this command in the shell:

```
mongo "mongodb://admin:admin@somehost:27003/mydb?replicaSet=myset" -eval 'db.version()'
```

outputs

> 3.6.6

If I run the command from inside the shell:

```
db.runCommand( { 'eval':'db.version()' } )
```

I'm also getting

> {
>           "operationTime" : Timestamp(1536931496, 11),
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "errmsg" : "not authorized on mydb to execute command { eval: \"db.version()\", $db: \"mydb\" }",
>           "code" : 13,
>           "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
>   }

The user I'm connecting with looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "mydb.admin",
    "user" : "admin",
    "db" : "mydb",
    "roles" : [
            {
                    "role" : "readWrite",
                    "db" : "mydb"
            },
            {
                    "role" : "dbAdmin",
                    "db" : "mydb"
            },
            {
                    "role" : "userAdmin",
                    "db" : "mydb"
            },
            {
                    "role" : "dbOwner",
                    "db" : "mydb"
            }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?
Do I need special privileges for `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per mongodb documentation, you need a role that grants [anyAction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#anyAction) on [AnyResource](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/resource-document/#resource-anyresource).